# How to Count Distinct for SAS PROC SQL with Rolling Date Window of 5 years?

Tags: sas, rolling-computation, distinct-values

I want to count the distinct values of a variable grouped by MEMBER_ID and a rolling date range of 5 years. I have seen a similar post.
[How to Count Distinct for SAS PROC SQL with Rolling Date Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67611814/how-to-count-distinct-for-sas-proc-sql-with-rolling-date-window/72605255?noredirect=1#comment128253809_72605255)

When I change h2.DATE BETWEEN h.DATE - 180 AND h.DATE to h2.year BETWEEN h.year-5 AND h.year, should it give me the correct distinct count within the last 5 years? Thank you in advance.

```
data have;
    input permno year Cand_ID$;
    datalines;
1 2000 1 
1 2001 2 
1 2002 3 
1 2003 1 
1 2004 3 
1 2005 1 
2 2000 1 
2 2001 3 
2 2002 1 
2 2003 2 
2 2004 2 
2 2005 2 
2 2006 1 
2 2007 1 
3 2001 3 
3 2002 3 
3 2003 3 
3 2004 1 
3 2005 1
;
run;
```

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on how your date/year variable is formatted. I'm assuming it did not work for you?

Comment: My data looks like this:
permno year Cand_ID
1 2000 1
1 2001 2
1 2002 3
1 2003 1
1 2004 3
1 2005 1
2 2000 1
2 2001 3
2 2002 1
2 2003 2
2 2004 2
2 2005 2
2 2006 1
2 2007 1
3 2001 3
3 2002 3
3 2003 3
3 2004 1
3 2005 1

Comment: I have a date variable as well year extracted from the date. I tried using the previous code by replacing date with year (as I want to count distant candidates in last 5 years). But proc SQL code is taking a lot of time.

Comment: You can use SQL but a data step is quicker and more efficient. Please update your question with your data and expected output and you should get some more help.

Comment: Should `permno` in your data actually be `MEMBER_ID` mentioned in your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it with a data step. This assumes you have values for all years. If you do not, fill it in with zeros.

Keep a rolling list of the last 5 years by using the `lag` function. If we keep a rolling sorted array list of the last 5 years using `lag`, we can count the distinct values for each row to get a rolling 5-year count.

In other words, we're going to create and count a list that looks like this:

```
permno  year    id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
1       2000    .   .   .   .   1   
1       2001    .   .   .   1   2   
1       2002    .   .   1   2   3   
1       2003    .   1   1   2   3
```

Code:

```
data want;
    set have;
    by permno year;

    array lagid[4] $;
    array id[5] $;

    id1    = cand_id;
    lagid1 = lag1(cand_id);
    lagid2 = lag2(cand_id);
    lagid3 = lag3(cand_id);
    lagid4 = lag4(cand_id);
    
    /* Reset the counter for the first group */
    if(first.permno) then n = 0;

    /* Count the number of rows within a group */
    n+1;

    /* Save the last 5 years by using the lag function, 
       but do not get lags from previous groups 
    */
    do i = 1 to 4;
        if(i < n) then id[i+1] = lagid[i];
    end;

    /* Sort the array of IDs into ascending order */
    call sortc(of id:);

    /* Count the number of distinct IDs in the array. Do not count
       missing values.
    */
    n_distinct = 1;

    do i = 2 to dim(id);
        if(id[i] > id[i-1] AND NOT missing(id[i-1]) ) then n_distinct+1;
    end;

    drop lag: n i;
run;
```

Output (without `id:` dropped):

```
permno  year    Cand_ID id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 n_distinct
1       2000    1       .   .   .   .   1   1
1       2001    2       .   .   .   1   2   2
1       2002    3       .   .   1   2   3   3
1       2003    1       .   1   1   2   3   3
1       2004    3       1   1   2   3   3   3
1       2005    1       1   1   2   3   3   3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code. I tried using it and I realized my Cand_ID is a character variable. Therefore, count does not work. Could you please help me to modify this data step? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Updated. Two changes: (1) We initialize our arrays as character with `$`. (2) Instead of using `sortn()`, we use `sortc()` which does the same thing except with character variables.